# How to take values in every other row (odd) and shift them to be in every row (even and odd) or switch them to other rows (even)?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

How do you take values in every other row (odd) and shift them to every row (even and odd) or switch them to other rows (even)? In a dataframe, I have values in every other row. I would like them to be in every row of the column. How do I achieve this? An alternative solution would be to switch them so that they are only in even, but not odd.

Example of what it currently looks like:

```
set.seed(5)
output<-data.frame(matrix("", nrow=500, ncol=1))
for(i in 1:nrow(output)){
  if(i %% 2 == 0){
    output[i,1] <- sample(c("A","B","C"),1,replace = T)
  }
}
colnames(output) <- "work"
```

I would like it to appear as:

```
set.seed(5)
output<-data.frame(matrix("", nrow=500, ncol=1))
for(i in 1:nrow(output)){
    output[i,1] <- sample(c("A","B","C"),1,replace = T)
}
colnames(output) <- "work"
```

Comment: "The question is fairly explicit." Not sure I can agree with that. May I suggest you make your examples shorter, e.g. 20 rows each?

Comment: so, how do you create the missing values. In first example, you have 250 values and 250 NAs, and in the second you have 500 values... Where do 250 new values come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  row_odd <- seq_len(nrow(output)) %% 2 
  output[row_odd == 1, 1] <- data_row_even
  output[row_odd == 0, 1] <- NA
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, create an index that selects the values you'd like

```
> idx = seq(2, nrow(output), by = 2)
```

and use `idx - 1` to select the rows to be replaced

```
> output[idx - 1, "work"] = output[idx, "work"]
> head(output)
  work
1    B
2    B
3    C
4    C
5    A
6    A
```

It's not really clear what you'd like to happen to the last row, if there are an odd number of rows?

Note that a much more efficient / R way to generate the original data is perhaps

```
df = data.frame(work = character(500))
idx = seq(2, nrow(df), by = 2)
df[idx, "work"] = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), length(idx), replace = TRUE)
```